# Can I connect to my app engine VM instance from my computer with SSH?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

1) Can I connect to my app engine VM instance from my computer with SSH ?

I speak well about the app engine part of google cloud platform.

For example, in my computer, I open a terminal, I enter

```
ssh root@ip
```

How to get the IP and the username for the app engine instance ? I Want to do the same thing that in the GCP Shell, but from my PC..

2) I have app engine and compute engine in my GCP panel. Are them interconnected themselves between or are they independent instances (app and compute) ?

I tried all the things in each menu of the gcp console and I did not find thing.

Answer (score 0):

On your console, go to the "Instances" tab:
[image: GCP Instances Tab]

Then click the "SSH" button next to your VM:
[image: Instance detail page]